# Adding Labels to Markers on Relplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am a bit lost on the best approach to add labels to my markers with a seaborn `relplot`. I see in the matplotlib documentation that there is a `axes.text()` method that looks to be the right approach, but it doesn't appear that this method exists. Does seaborn behave differently than matplotlib in this sense? What would the right approach be?

Error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'text'`

Code:

```
line_minutes_asleep = sns.relplot(
    x = "sleep_date",
    y = "minutes_asleep",
    kind = "line",
    data = df,
    height=10, # make the plot 5 units high
    aspect=3
)

x = df.sleep_date
y = df.minutes_asleep
names = df.minutes_asleep

print(line_minutes_asleep.axes.text())
```

Answer (score 0):

[`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) returns a FacetGrid, which is a figure containing several subplots. The property `.axes` of a FacetGrid is a 2D ndarray of `Axes` objects. Therefore, you need to use `FacetGrid.axes[i,j]` to get a reference to the subplot.

If you want to write something in the first subplot (axes[0,0]), at the position x,y=(20,5), you would need to do:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.relplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="day", data=tips)

g.axes[0,0].text(20,5,"this is a text")
```